# How do I rotate object around a point without spinning the object itself?

Tags: animation

I want to create a London Eye kind of a thing and I want to rotate the whole thing. The problem is that I want those cabins to stay with their roof facing up. I want them to move in circle but not to rotate.
Do you know, how can i do that?[image]

Comment: A search on 'Ferris Wheel' will turn up quite a few answers to this one.. :)

Comment: Not really a lot of answers, but some worth looking at: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=Ferris+Wheel

Answer (score 2):

You can parent the cabins (here Suzanne) to the circle and give them a *Limit Rotation* constraint

Or you can parent empties to the circle and give each cabin a *Copy Location* constraint with the empties as *Target*:

[image]